# .htaccess redirect home.html to root but allow query strings

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to 301 redirect home.html to the root to avoid duplicate content. I can do this like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/home.html$ / [NC,R=301]
```

However there is a legacy affiliate program that use home.html like this:

```
home.html?a=companyname
```

Is there a way to allow the affiliate links, but still 301 home.html?

Comment: Incidentally, you need to remove the leading / from your match string (i.e., it should be `^home.html$`. Search [this page of the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for "leading slash" for further info.

Answer (score 0):

The query string will be appended automatically.  From the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> **Modifying the Query String**
>
> By default, the query string is passed through unchanged. You can, however, create URLs in the substitution string containing a query string part. Simply use a question mark inside the substitution string to indicate that the following text should be re-injected into the query string. When you want to erase an existing query string, end the substitution string with just a question mark. To combine new and old query strings, use the [QSA] flag.